# Remove space between buttons Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, space

Where I can find the option to remove a space between buttons?

***Part of the code with buttons:***

[image]

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
      
  Widget _bulidLoginFacebook() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => print('Facebook Login'),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        color: Color(0xFF3b5998),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Zaloguj się z ',
                style: TextStyle(color: ColorSs.white, letterSpacing: 1.5, fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
              ),
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 14,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: ' FACEBOOK',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bulidLoginGoogle() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => print('Google Login'),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        color: Color(0xFFde5246),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Zaloguj się z ',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 1.5, fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
              ),
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 14,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: ' GOOGLE',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 1.5, fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

***Here's my screenshot of what im trying to do i'm creating a sign in page using google sign-in and facebook sign-in***

[image]

Comment: `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 0` to both buttons

Comment: Can you show where you call these widgets?

Comment: @Santiago Curvello  Please look down

Answer (score 0):

Set the  `materialTapTargetSize` of your button to `shrinkWrap`

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  child: child,
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 60,
                  vertical: 40
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
             
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/logofl.png',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  _bulidEmailTF(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  _bulidPasswordTF(),
                  _bulidForgotPasswordBtn(),
                  _bulidLoginButton(),
                  _bulidRegistrationTF(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  _bulidLine(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  _bulidLoginFacebook(),
                  _bulidLoginGoogle(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```